# Getting average low and high bids in SQL

Tags: sql

I am pretty new to SQL and am working with a (what I expected to be easy) little bidding tool.

I am trying to compute average lows and highs from the same column. I have managed to figure out how to use SQL's MIN, MAX, AVG functions, but how would I go about averaging MIN and MAX?

This is the query I am using:

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT AVG(bid),MIN(bid),MAX(bid) FROM bidding WHERE bid_id=:bid_id GROUP BY bid_id");
```

Comment: if i got this right, you're looking for the average of the max and min value. Am I wrong?

Comment: Average of min and max is the average for the min and max of all your columns ? Or by bid_id ?

Comment: Columns are named a bit funny, but bid_id is for per item. So it is all bids for that item.

And yes, the average of max and min. I am assuming I would set some kind of limit based on average to calculate the high and low averages.

Comment: The average of the max and min of each bid is a completely useless value, just saying. If you have 1000 bids at value 1 and one bid at value 1000 you'll have: MIN(bid) = 1, MAX(bid) = 1000, AVG(bid) = 1.998, average of min(bid) and max(bid) = 500.5. What's that useful for, @AndreasEkholm?

Comment: I realise that which is why I raised this question, I don't even know if what I am asking for is possible with my database design. But essentially to give out 3 averages. Let's say you are listing an item, and it'll tip you "hey, the average for this is: #" , "people have sold it for as much/little as: #/#". But to exclude stupid results as 2 and 99999 in case of not seen listing or whatever. I hope this makes sense somewhat.

Answer (score 1):

As You are saying you need to find out the Min of Avg and Max of Avg,
Now what you are doing is group on one column this means Avg(Bid) will return only one value. And the thing that you are doing will make sense only if it is done with two column,

For example you wanna know the min of Averages per day. You need to identify one more column on which base you want to find out max and min of Avg. See in my example i am using Date as second column. the query will go like.

```
Select Max(MAx_Bid),Min(Min_Bid),Min(Avg_Bid),Max(Avg_Bid) FROM
(SELECT AVG(bid) Avg_Bid,MIN(bid) Mix_Bid,MAX(bid) max_bid FROM bidding WHERE bid_id=:bid_id GROUP BY bid_id,Days_Date(Dummy column))A
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following query to accomplish task

```
SELECT ((max(bid)+min(bid))/2) as average FROM bidding WHERE bid_id=:bid_id GROUP BY bid_id
```

Because the predefined avg function takes only one argument that may be column from table or single value. So you have to find the average of the min and max value of bid like above